# Why aren't my words staying inside of my div

Tags: html, css

I created a header for a website im doing but the words wont stay inside of it, they go below it. Please help. Heres the code:

```css
#headerclasshomenofix{
 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 position:absolute;
 font-family:"AR CENA";
 border-bottom:thick gray solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerclasshomenofix">
  <h1><i>Music School</i></h1>
</div>
```

See how the "Music School" words float down.. I don't know what i did wrong.

Comment: Reset the h1 default margin .... `h1{margin:0}`

Comment: 40px does not accommodate the h1 tags top/bottom margin

Comment: remove position:absolute

Comment: also, just to state this, you can use hyphens in your css class names, which makes it more readable. It won't do anything other than improve readability, but maybe changing your class name to `header-class-home-nofix` might make things easier for you down the road.

Comment: @De'Shaun You are using same styles in inline and also internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default many tags like the `h1` has default values on some properties like this for the **h1** on Chrome:

> ```
> h1 {
>     display: block;
>     font-size: 2em;
>     -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
>     -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
>     -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
>     -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
>     font-weight: bold;
> }
> ```

Therefore you just need to reset the default `margin`

```css
#headerclasshomenofix {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "AR CENA";
  border-bottom: thick gray solid;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="headerclasshomenofix" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
  <h1><i>Music School</i></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @De'Shaun glad to help U mate don't forget to mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Your element is too small to fit this kind of font size. I am assuming you want to keep position: absolute. Do one of these:

- reduce `font-size`
- remove or increase `height` (60px works fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the position absolute css from #hearderclasshomenofix

```css
#headerclasshomenofix{
 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 font-family:"AR CENA";
 border-bottom:thick gray solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerclasshomenofix" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
  <h1><i>Music School</i></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely, what the issue is?
If it's how the words/css appear on the page - you can change
`position absolute` to `position static`

Also you probably want to keep consistent with the height being in pixels and width being in percentage.

If you mean the actual elements, in the code, the code looks fine? The H1 and  tag should be inside your div like that?

Answer (score 0):

just set `h1{margin:0;padding:0;}`

```css
#headerclasshomenofix{

 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 position:absolute;
 font-family:"AR CENA";
 border-bottom:thick gray solid;
}
h1{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<div id="headerclasshomenofix" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
  <h1><i>Music School</i></h1>
</div>
```